# Save session/cookies like discord in php

Tags: php, session-cookies

I would like to save sessions and cookies as discord does. What i mean? I mean when user sign in to discord account on browser and delete all cookies/session on browser by clicking padlock and cookies. When that will deleted everytime session file is created. And when i refresh site i was still logged on account. I want do something on this same way but when i use session, cookies, Header (to header i cant add expires date) And delete cookies by this same way it not adding that again because my script cant get any information about user. I thinking to do a JavaScript while to add every second sessionstorage or localstorage. And check that everytime when user open site but that is not good for optimalization. So anyone had idea how to do that?

**Update**
CreateInfo.php

```
<?php
namespace Client\Info;

use Client\Info\CheckInfo;
use Client\Info\SetInfo;

class CreateInfo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->checkInfo    = new CheckInfo();
        $this->setInfo      = new SetInfo();

        $this->status       = $this->checkInfo->getStatus();
    }

    public function control()
    {
        if($this->status['session'] && $this->status['cookie'] && $this->status['sameCookieSession']){
            if(!$this->checkInfo->checkIpStatus()){
                $this->setInfo->addIp(true, true, true);
            }
        }else if($this->status['session'] && $this->status['cookie'] && !$this->status['sameCookieSession']){
            $this->setInfo->addCookie(true);

            if(!$this->checkInfo->checkIpStatus()){
                $this->setInfo->addIp(true, true, false);
            }

        }else if($this->status['session'] && !$this->status['cookie']){
            $this->setInfo->addCookie(true);

            if(!$this->checkInfo->checkIpStatus()){
                $this->setInfo->addIp(true, false, false);
            }

        }else if(!$this->status['session'] && $this->status['cookie']){
            $this->setInfo->addSession(true);

            if(!$this->checkInfo->checkIpStatus()){
                $this->setInfo->addIp(false, true, false);
            }           
        }else{
            $this->setInfo->setAll();
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->control();
    }
}
```

CheckInfo.php

```
<?php
namespace Client\Info;

use Client\Info\InfoDatabase;
use Client\Cookie\CookieFunction;
use Client\Session\SessionFunction;
use Client\Ip\IpFunction;

class CheckInfo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->infoDatabase      = new InfoDatabase();
        $this->cookieFunction  = new CookieFunction();
        $this->sessionFunction = new SessionFunction();
        $this->ipFunction        = new IpFunction();

        $this->session = $this->sessionFunction->getSession('client');
        $this->cookie  = $this->cookieFunction->getCookie('client');
    }

    public function checkExist($data)
    {
        if(!isset($data) || empty($data)){
            return false;
        }

        if(!$this->infoDatabase->checkExistInDb($data)){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        if($this->checkExist($this->cookie)){
            if($this->checkExist($this->session)){
                if($this->cookie == $this->session){
                    return[
                        'session'                   => true,
                        'cookie'                        => true,
                        'sameCookieSession' => true
                    ];
                }else{
                    return[
                        'session'                   => true,
                        'cookie'                        => true,
                        'sameCookieSession' => false
                    ];
                }
            }else{
                return[
                    'session'                   => false,
                    'cookie'                        => true,
                    'sameCookieSession' => false
                ];
            }
        }else{
            if($this->checkExist($this->session)){
                return[
                    'session'                       => true,
                    'cookie'                        => false,
                    'sameCookieSession' => false
                ];
            }else{
                return[
                    'session'                   => false,
                    'cookie'                        => false,
                    'sameCookieSession' => false
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    public function checkIpStatus()
    {
        $ip = $this->ipFunction->getIp();

        $result = false;

        if($this->getStatus()['session']){
            $result = $this->infoDatabase->checkExistIpInDb($this->session, $ip);
        }else if($this->getStatus()['cookie']){
            $result = $this->infoDatabase->checkExistIpInDb($this->cookie, $ip);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

SetInfo.php

```
<?php
namespace Client\Info;

use Client\Info\InfoDatabase;
use Client\Cookie\CookieFunction;
use Client\Session\SessionFunction;
use Client\Ip\IpFunction;
use Client\Currency\CurrencyFunction;
use App\Element\Random\RandomString;

class SetInfo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->infoDatabase       = new InfoDatabase();
        $this->cookieFunction   = new CookieFunction();
        $this->sessionFunction  = new SessionFunction();
        $this->ipFunction         = new IpFunction();
        $this->currencyFunction = new CurrencyFunction();
        $this->randomString       = new RandomString();
    
        $this->cookie  = $this->cookieFunction->getCookie('client');
        $this->session = $this->sessionFunction->getSession('client');
    }

    public function addIp($session, $cookie, $sameCookieSession)
    {
        $ip = $this->ipFunction->getIp();

        if($sameCookieSession){
            $this->infoDatabase->addIp($this->cookie, $ip);
        }else{
            if($session){
                $this->infoDatabase->addIp($this->session, $ip);
            }else if($cookie){
                $this->infoDatabase->addIp($this->cookie, $ip);
            }
        }
    }

    public function addCookie($session)
    {
        if($session){
            $this->cookieFunction->setCookie('client', $this->session);
        }
    }

    public function addSession($cookie)
    {
        if($cookie){
            $this->sessionFunction->setSession('client', $this->cookie);
        }
    }

    public function setAll()
    {
        $rand       = $this->randomString->generate(128);
        $ip             = $this->ipFunction->getIp();
        $currency = $this->currencyFunction->getCurrencyCode();

        $this->infoDatabase->addCookie($rand);
        $this->infoDatabase->addIp($rand, $ip);
        $this->infoDatabase->addCurrency($rand, $currency);
        $this->cookieFunction->setCookie('client', $rand);
        $this->sessionFunction->setSession('client', $rand);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done thus far? Can you post some code here?

Comment: Sure thread updated